# Codeigniter "where" and "or_where"

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to do the following SQL query with the active record of codeigniter:

`SELECT * FROM USERS_OPTIONS WHERE user_id = 3 AND ( option_id = 2 OR option_id = 5 OR option_id = 108 OR .... )`

For that, I have this code in codeigniter, but it's not working:

```
$this -> db -> where("user_id", $user_id);

foreach( $options as $option ){
    $this -> db -> or_where("option_id" , $option["id"]  );
}
```

$options is an array where I store all the options_id I need.

If I try any of the 2 querys separately, them work. But I'm not able to mix the 2 conditions.

How can I get this?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$this->db->where_in()` :

> Generates a WHERE field IN ('item', 'item') SQL query joined with AND
>   if appropriate

```
$names = array('Frank', 'Todd', 'James');
$this->db->where_in('username', $names);
// Produces: AND username IN ('Frank', 'Todd', 'James')
```

In your case, you will have :

```
$this->db->where_in('option_id', $options)
         ->get_where("your_table", array("user_id" => $user_id))->result();
```

Doc : https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->select()->from('USERS_OPTIONS')->where("user_id $user_id AND (

// LOOP THROUGH PHP TO PRINT SOME THING LIKE or_where

));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try `$this->db->where_in();`. First collect all option ids & then use it like this:

> Generates a WHERE field IN ('item', 'item') SQL query joined with AND if appropriate

```
$names = array('Frank', 'Todd', 'James');
$this->db->where_in('username', $names);
// Produces: AND username IN ('Frank', 'Todd', 'James')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code and you can not concatenate the AND OR condition using active records methods.

```
//Filtering by user
$where_condition = "(user_id = '".$user_id."')";

//Filtering by options
if(count($options)){

    $where_condition .= " AND (";

    foreach( $options as $option ){
        $where_condition .= "option_id = '".$option["id"]."' OR ";
    }

    $where_condition = substr($where_condition, 0, -3); //Remove last 3 characters OR with space

    $where_condition = $where_condition. ")";

}

//Select data                   
$this->db->select('*'); 
$this->db->from("TABLE_NAME");
$this->db->where($where_condition);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally this is the best way I found to achieve this using the active record:

With an array like:

```
$options = array ( option_id1 , option_id2, ... , option_idn );

$this -> db -> where("id_user", $id_user);
$this -> db -> where_in("id_option" , $options  );
```

This give me exactly what I wanted and it's pretty clear